# Does the mean method in pandas include nan in its calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a big dataframe with large number of nan cells.
Does the mean function include nan cells in its calculation in python?

Comment: See [nanmean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html)

Comment: Python doesn't _have_ dataframes. I guess you are using pandas? Please _always_ include the [tag:pandas] tag when asking about pandas or other libraries that bring new data types to Python, as described in the Python tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `skipna=True` or `skipna=False`

```
DataFrame.mean( axis=None, 
                skipna=True, # If you set skipna to True it will skip NaN
                level=None, 
                numeric_only=None, 
                **kwargs)
```

> skipna    Boolean. Exclude NaN values (skipna=True) or include NaN values (skipna=False)